# Storing audio extracted on aws polly, store it on S3 and upload it on html element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Below is my code I have hide my accesskey and id. The audio is returned as a blob url, which cannot play when uploaded on audio file. How is the audio file stored in aws s3

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2'

var polly = new AWS.Polly()

var  params = {
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    Text: 'Hello David, How are you?',
    TextType: 'text',
    VoiceId: 'Joanna',
    SampleRate: '22050'
}

polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function (err, data) {
// if (err) {
//     console.log(err, err.stack)
// }else {
//     var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(data.AudioStream);
//     var arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer
//     var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])

//     var audio = document.querySelector('audio')
//     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
//     audio[0].src = url
//     audio[0].play()
// }
// (err) ? console.log(err, err.stack) : console.log(data)
if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack)
}else {
    console.log(data)
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(data.AudioStream)
    var arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer])
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    var audioElement = document.querySelector('source')
    console.log(audioElement)
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', url)
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a AWS.Polly.Presigner object, then create the presigned URL from which the synthesized speech audio can be retrieved. Once it's returned, simply add it as the source in your HTML.

Then, use the `startSpeechSynthesisTask` method which enables the creation of an asynchronous synthesis task. This operation requires all the standard information needed for speech synthesis, plus the name of the output S3 bucket. See the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_StartSpeechSynthesisTask.html) for more info.; and the blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-polly-update-time-driven-prosody-and-asynchronous-synthesis/).

```
var polly = new AWS.Polly({region:"eu-west-1"});
var signer = new AWS.Polly.Presigner(urlParams, polly);
var s3 = new AWS.S3({region:"eu-west-1"})
var  urlParams = {
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    Text: 'Hello David, How are you?',
    TextType: 'text',
    VoiceId: 'Joanna',
    SampleRate: '22050'
};

var  s3Params = {
    OutputFormat: 'mp3',
    OutputS3BucketName: "BUCKET_NAME",
    Text: 'Hello David, How are you?',
    TextType: 'text',
    VoiceId: 'Joanna',
    SampleRate: '22050'
};

signer.getSynthesizeSpeechUrl(urlParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack)
    }else {
            console.log("Success, presigned url created", data);
        }
    })

polly.startSpeechSynthesisTask(s3Params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack)
    }else {
        console.log("Success, audio file uploaded", data);
    }
})
```